# Daled v'Hei: Repeating a sin?

Tags: talmud-bavli, gezel-stealing, bava-kamma

The fine of Daled v'Hei ("4 and 5") is awarded to a person who not only stole a sheep or cow (respectively), but also sold or shechted it ([Shemos 21:37](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.37?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Rava ([BK 68a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.68a.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) explains that it's because he "repeated his sin."

Wait, what?

Sure, he did two sins, but how is it repeating a sin?

---

***This is part of the [Daf Yomi Challenge.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Daf+yomi+challenge)***

Comment: "Sure, he did two sins"? Is slaughtering an animal a sin?

Comment: Indeed what is the second sin, if not theft again?

Comment: Slaughtering an animal that's not yours without permission? How is that not nezek?

Comment: Your translation of the language *might* be off - regarding theft we have a concept of being mishaneh and chozer libriyaso - changing a stolen item from its original state and returning it TO it's original state. Unlike stealing an inanimate object, slaughtering an animal is an irreversible at - you have performed a permanent shinui on the object. This does not explain, however, why this additional penalty isn't applied with other animals...

Answer (score 3):

The [Steinsaltz](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.68a.24?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Bava_Kamma.68a.24&lang2=bi) translates "מפני ששנה בחטא" differently:

> **מפני ששנה בחטא**, שלא רק שחטא בכך שגנב, אלא הוסיף חטא אחר על כך למוכרו.
>
> Not only did he sin in that he stole, rather he added an additional sin afterwards by selling it

Namely, NOT that he repeated his sin, but rather the person committed an ***additional*** sin.